# Rails - binding versus not binding a rails collection select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I was experiencing an error when I was attaching a collection_select to my form_for object like so:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:city_id,  @cities,  :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a City"}, {:id => 'cities_select', multiple: true}) %>
```

and getting the error:

```
undefined local variable 'city_id'
```

But when I don't bind the select like so:

```
<%= collection_select(nil, :city_id,  @cities,  :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a City"}, {:id => 'cities_select', multiple: true}) %>
```

It works fine.

I just want to understand the theory behind why one works and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's tripping you up, primarily, is the concepts you have of what's going on here.

Nothing is “binding” anything to anything by calling a method on a form helper object. There are form helper methods, like `collection_select`, that can be used to build HTML elements. There are form builders that have methods, like `collection_select` that build HTML form elements for a form tied to an object.

The issue you're having here is that the `FormOptionsHelper#collection_select` method and the `FormBuilder#collection_select` method are not the same method and do not accept the same arguments:

[FormOptionsHelper#collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) vs [FormBuilder#collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_select)

Pay particular attention to the arguments provided. It's also worth noticing that `FormBuilder` essentially [delegates this work](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fdcd7c0f2ee264219c322e5cb8f880ca48e14d5f/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb#L645) to the template (i.e. `FormOptionsHelper`) and adjusts the arguments as needed.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at the documentation!